# Position of BooleanField is odd on RAP target in Eclipse Scout

Tags: position, boolean, eclipse-scout

I have one problem.

I make Boolean Field in Eclipse Scout and I positioned it :

```
- Lable Width In Pixel = 1
- Fill Horizontal : NO
- Grid Weight X = 1
- Width in Pixel  = 160
```

On Swing it looks ok : (Field Margin)

[image]

but on RAP it look odd like those field would not be set :

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out, thanks to https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/640392/.

Problem is that RAP target ignore property :

```
- Lable Width In Pixel
```

To go around, you set

```
- Lable visible : NO
```